# .Net 4.6 equivalent of .NET Core Identity password hashing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a requirement where I need to be able to create a user via a ASP.NETCore based web application and also via a windows application(.NET 4.6). The same user could be used to login to both the Web Site and the WindowsApp. The credential store used is a SQL Server database. I am using ASP.NET Core Identity with the default PasswordHashing implementation for the Web Application. But the problem that I am having is in trying to replicate the same PasswordHashing algorithm when creating users via the WindowsApplication. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can configure the ASP.NET Core Identity PasswordHashing implementation to use the V2 version - thus aligning with the behaviour of Identity 2 (that I'm guessing you're using in the .NET framework Windows app).

In the startup.cs of the web application, add this line:

```
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);
```

All passwords created through web will have to be reset.

Comment: Thanks for that. Only problem with this is that I would have to stick to the old implementation of the password hasher. I eventually went down this route,

https://lockmedown.com/hash-right-implementing-pbkdf2-net/